# How convert base64 to image(canvas) and save it to folder path with php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, base64

I am confused as how to upload that base64 to folder path. Here is my code:

```
var img = document.createElement('img') || document.querySelector('img');
var context;
var width = video.offsetWidth
        , height = video.offsetHeight;

canvas = canvas || document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I used this and it worked:

`$picture = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($_FILES['userfile']['name']), '+/', '-_'), '=');`

For the view:

`img src=" echo base_url(). 'admin/assets/uploads/product/'.$product['userfile'];" alt="img" class = "img-thumbnail rounded float-left image-product"`

Comment: please im just new in html, i need full script '-'

Comment: sorry i use only this code in my project for upload image using base64 and its worked..not able to give you whole project code

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is pass your image data to an PHP file to save this data to an image by decoding it by this function `base64_decode($data);`, `$data` is your image data.

You can pass this data by storing it in a hidden input in your HTML

First, make the hidden input :

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="">
   <input name="hidden_data" id='hidden_data' type="hidden"/>
</form>`
```

Then store the image data into it by this js code

```
document.getElementById('hidden_data').value = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

Here you can pass this data to PHP by submiting the form data

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
form.submit();
```

In the PHP you can save the file by decoding the image base64 data first:

```
if(isset($_POST['hidden_data']){
    $img = $_POST['hidden_data'];

    //Extracting the base64 data from the passed string
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);

    //Decoding the image data 
    $data = base64_decode($img);

    //Choosing file name based on current time (unique name)
    $fileName = mktime() . ".png";

    $upload_dir = "./MyImages";
    $file = $upload_dir . $fileName;

    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    if($success){
      echo "Image Saved";
    }else{
      echo "Couldn't Save Image";
    }
}
```

You can choose another way to pass the data may be AJAX GET request or something, but you got the idea.